# Export does not include keyframed properties

Tags: export, bones, keyframes, properties, nla-editor

My animations have keyframes on the "Inherit Rotation" property, as it is used in some animations, but not all. I see that this keyframes are not stored in object, like all other animations, but only in the armature. Seen in the action editor I named it Inspector.

Everything looks good in blender, but these keyframes do not transfer to Unity. So it seems that the exported FBX does not include the changes on the armature action channel. What should I do different?

[image: Inherit Rotation]

[image]

Comment: I turn on/off "Inherit Rotation" because I also turn on/off IK influence, where I want the hands to be stuck to a object that is pushed.